# Android NDK Cmake Linking .a (Static) Libs

Tags: android, android-ndk, linker, cmake, linker-errors

I am using Android Studio 2.2.2 with cmake and Android NDK. I have a problem linking .a library (Static lib).

Here is my cmake:

```
# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build the native
# library. You should either keep the default value or only pass a
# value of 3.4.0 or lower.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)

# Creates and names a library, sets it as either STATIC
# or SHARED, and provides the relative paths to its source code.
# You can define multiple libraries, and CMake builds it for you.    
# Gradle automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.  

add_library(lib_webp SHARED IMPORTED )
set_target_properties(lib_webp PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
src/main/jni/${ANDROID_ABI}/libwebp.so)


add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
         game-lib

         # Sets the library as a shared library.
         SHARED

         # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
         # Associated headers in the same location as their source
         # file are automatically included.
         src/main/cpp/main.cpp
         src/main/cpp/android_native_app_glue.c            
         )


target_include_directories(game-lib PRIVATE
 ../../../../libs/headers/android
)

include_directories($ENV{NDK_MODULE_PATH}/sources/android/native_app_glue/)

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in the
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                   game-lib

                   # Links the target library to the log library
                   # included in the NDK.
                   # ${log-lib}                        


                     # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
                     # you want CMake to locate.
                     log                        
                     android
                     OpenSLES
                     z
                     GLESv2
                     EGL
                     dl                         
                  )

add_definitions(-g -DANDROID -Wno-write-strings -fsigned-char -Wno-conversion-null)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(game-lib libtheoraplayer.a)
```

My linker reports an error

> arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: error: cannot find -ltheoraplayer
>
> error: undefined reference to 'TheoraVideoManager::TheoraVideoManager(int)'

which is a part of libtheoraplayer.a. Did anyone had similar problem? Any idea how to solve this?

I have the Static lib libtheoraplayer.a present at that location. I even have the Shared lib also, libtheoraplayer.so but I can`t link it either.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: `I have the Static lib libtheoraplayer.a present at that location.` - Where **exactly** do you have this library? I see no `link_directories` calls in you code, so why do you expect a linker to find the library?

Comment: I am new to cmake so please forgive me if I ask stupid questions. I used the old system with Android.mk for Android NDK. I am not aware that I need link_directories? The lib is the Theora Player already built (https://www.theora.org) and I need to import it to my project. link_directioris should point to the source file of Theora?

Comment: You need to point CMake where it should search library for link. There are several ways to do that: Using **absolute path** to the library file in `target_link_libraries`, or using *IMPORT*ed **library target** with absolute path, or using 'link_directories' call with *directory* where to search the library. In all cases the library file is `libtheoraplayer.a`, which you mention in the question.

Comment: Well I have TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(game-lib libtheoraplayer.a) at the end of the file, please check the file I added in the question. I will try to move this to another location and give a relative path to it.

Comment: Again, you use **non-absolute filename** for library. CMake (linker) tries to find this library .. and fails. This is what the error message talks about. CMake *doesn't automatically search* libraries in current source/build directory, you need to specify this **explicitely** using one of the ways I describe above.

Comment: Yep, with absolute it finds it. I have other errors but unrelated to this. I was using relative path always... Thank you ! Can I import .so (Shared lib) also like this? Or there is something special for .so ?

Comment: Yes, the same approaches can be used for shared libraries. BTW, you may find usefull [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/target_link_libraries.html) about `target_link_libraries`.

Comment: Thank you. You saved me a lot of time.. I was breaking my head on this...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127105/discussion-between-adrian-ivasku-and-tsyvarev).

Comment: When I use it like .so when I start my game I get linker error again, "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libtheoraplayer.so" not found". Did you run into this kind of problems maybe ?

Comment: i'm having the same dlopen error as above, did you figure out a solution? i.e. how to get the prebuilt shared lib on to the device?

Comment: This thread is the greatest thing that ever happened. This helped me solve a dependency issue I've been working on for months...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To post the answer. As Tsyvarev said, the problem with non-absolute file name for library. When I used absoulte path it worked like a charm.

Thank you.
Cheers.

Comment: I managed to link .a libraries with relative path too. Here is an example: target_link_libraries(game ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../libs/cricket/lib/libck.a)

Comment: You should put your comment in the answer because the comment is the answer. A bit frustrating having to edit this when upgrading Android studio. But it works.