# Failed to define absolute path of static libraries using CMake variable PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk

I am trying to build an Android NDK project using CMake. My project has dependencies of some pre-built static libraries like ***libcurl***. I was struggling to link those libraries with my own native library, then I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358365/android-ndk-cmake-linking-a-static-libs). It said to put absolute paths for the static libraries, and that's where I am facing a problem now.

I found a CMake [variable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR.html) named `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR`, which I suppose my project root directory as per the documentation. But when I tried to use that variable into my **CMakeList.txt** file, it gives the following error:

```
Build command failed.
Error while executing process /Users/sdsl/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/cmake with arguments {--build /Users/sdsl/Documents/AfriGIS-SB/GitLab/AGMapKit3dDroid/agmapkit3d_droid/mapkit3dapp/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/x86_64 --target mapkit-engine}
ninja: error: '../../../../mapkit3dapp/src/main/jni/CoreClasses/Libraries/droid/libcurl/x86_64/libcurl.a', needed by '../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/x86_64/libmapkit-engine.so', missing and no known rule to make it
```

Here is my **CMakeLists.txt** file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             mapkit-engine

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             src/main/jni/MKMapJNI.cpp
             src/main/jni/CoreClasses/IMKCPlatform.cpp)

# Specifies a path to native header files.
include_directories(src/main/jni/CoreClasses/)
include_directories(src/main/jni/CoreClasses/Libraries/droid/libcurl/include/)

find_library(log-lib log)
find_library(android-lib android)
target_link_libraries(mapkit-engine ${log-lib} ${android-lib})

target_link_libraries(mapkit-engine ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/mapkit3dapp/src/main/jni/CoreClasses/Libraries/droid/libcurl/${ANDROID_ABI}/libcurl.a)
```

I can assure that my static libraries are stored inside my project directory properly. And if I tried to navigate to my project root directory by clicking that `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR` variable, it takes me to the root directory into the IDE.

Comment: Please, show **absolute path** to the library file, which you actually have. BTW, if you suspect that a variable's value is not what you expect, you may always print it with `message()` command and check its output. Also, the `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR` variable's description notes about `project()`, but you doesn't have it in your code. (Well, sometimes CMake adds `project()` call *automatically*, but it is better to specify it *explicitly*).

Comment: My actual path to the library is `/Users/sdsl/Documents/AfriGIS-SB/GitLab/AGMapKit3dDroid/agmapkit3d_droid/mapkit3dapp`. I print the `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR` value with `message()` and it actually points to the source directory where the `CMakeLists.txt` file locates. I was assuming that it points to the root source directory of my Android app. And yes `project()` call is not required to invoke. Thanks for your suggestion to print that variable with `message()`, which actually works to find the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out that my understanding was not correct for the cmake variable `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR`, the official documentation is also not like crystal clear about it's actual outcome.

> Top level source directory for the current project.
>
> This is the source directory of the most recent project() command.

But in most Android NDK projects using cmake build, it's quite normal not to call the `project()` command manually. And is that cases the `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR` variable points to the src directory where **CMakeLists.txt** is located.

In my case, my root src directory was: `/Users/sdsl/Documents/AfriGIS-SB/GitLab/AGMapKit3dDroid/agmapkit3d_droid/`. And the `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR` is pointing to: `/Users/sdsl/Documents/AfriGIS-SB/GitLab/AGMapKit3dDroid/agmapkit3d_droid/mapkit3dapp/`.

That is also the directory where I have put the **CMakeLists.txt** file. Thanks to [Tsyvarev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3440745/tsyvarev), for helping me to figure out what actually the `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR` results in execution.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're off by one. Try

```
${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jni/CoreClasses/Libraries/droid/libcurl/${ANDROID_ABI}/libcurl.a
```

Comment: yes, that's what I mentioned in reply of @Tsyvarev comment.